# Open a web service url in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this script in php that opnes a web service url to send an sms

```
<?php

$amount = 300;
$url = 'http://sms.com.co/webservice/sms.php?method=Submit&account=adam&password=123456&mobile=773839&content=helloworld;'

echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

In nodejs i have this

```
var urllib = require('urllib');

urllib.request('http://sms.com.co/webservice/sms.php?method=Submit&account=adam&password=123456&mobile=773839&content=helloworld');
```

I am looking for a function or package in meteor that i can use so that i can avoid installing the urllib npm package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "[HTTP](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/http)" for this.

```
HTTP.call('get', 'http://sms.com.co/webservice/sms.php', {
  params: {
    method: 'Submit',
    account: 'adam',
    password: '123456',
    mobile: '773839',
    content: 'helloworld'
  }}, function(err, res) {
     // do stuff
  })
```

Upon calling this from your Meteor method will be asynchronous. Your method will not wait for the response from the HTTP call. In order to do so you need to use wrapAsync like this:

```
var convertAsyncToSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(HTTP.get),
            apiCall = convertAsyncToSync(yourURLHere, {params});
        if (apiCall.statusCode === 200) {
           // do stuff
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need "HTTP" from the Meteor core libraries. See http://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html for details. Install it using:

```
meteor add http
```

This lets you open a URL using either a method or without a method from the server:

```
HTTP.call('get', 'http://sms.com.co/webservice/sms.php', {
  params: {
    method: 'Submit',
    account: 'adam',
    password: '123456',
    mobile: '773839',
    content: 'helloworld'
  }}, function(err, res) {
     // do stuff
  })
```